# Graphics in/with SharePoint 2010

Tags: image, powerpivot

I'd like to know if it's possible to Is it possible to generate graphics in/with SharePoint 2010 as Excel used to generate graphics and curve based on datas. I have heard about PowerPivot but don't really think is the best solution.
Any ideas?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Its not clear to me what you're asking - could you clarify a little please? Are you looking to generate charts and graphs or something else and what does powerpoint have to do with your requirement?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes i definetely want to generate charts and graphs in/with SharePoint based on datasets. I read somewhere that PowerPivot (not Powerpoint) can be a solution but i'm not sure of that.

Comment: have you tried the charts web part?

Comment: Oh - PowerPivot! I read PowerPoint, me bad ;)

Comment: Any of these any good? http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=sharepoint+chart+web+part

Comment: Thanks for all your answers.Ok i'm working on the charts web part right now. But is it possible to export these charts in Excel for example.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to those already mentioned, you can use [Excel Services REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee556413.aspx) to generate graphs that are then shown in you page. This is actually a surprisingly powerful feature that doesn't seem to get a lot of publicity.

Comment: Thanks SPDoctor. I'm going to look on this new solution!

Answer (score 2):

Option 1 is Excel Web Part (Enterprise license)
Option 2 is Charts Web Part (also Enterprise license)
Option 3 are BI components: PowerPivot or PerformancePoint (Enterprise license)

all other options are 3rd party tools.